# Problem With Getting Permission (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) at Runtime

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I have written the following code for getting the user location, but the application keeps crashing. It may be due to the version of the Android Studio that I am using.

```
package com.example.userlocationmap;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length >= 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);//get the location locater service running
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {//listening in on your current location
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                //when location is changed
                Log.i("location", location.toString());//printing location to logs
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                //when location is enabled on mobile
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                //when location is disabled on mobile
            }
        };

        //checking if the version of android is before marshmellow (SDK version 23)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        } else {
            //checking whether we have permission to access the user location
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                //checking if permission is not granted. if not granted then ask for it.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                //this asks for permission which is stored in an array String
            } else {
                //if we already have permission
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Please tell me what are the changes that are required to be made so that the code can be run on the emulator.

Comment: Is the program returning an error message when it crashes? If so, posting that error message in your question would be useful.

Comment: Please add what error you are getting.. and how are you running your application

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length >= 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);//after getting permission get locationManager
                if(locationManager != null)// prevent NullPointerException
                   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `permission` is added in Manifest file.